# Use boolean operation like a cookie cutter on 3d mesh in blender

Tags: 3d, blender, difference, boolean-operations

I am trying to remove the outer part of these objects (soil samples) to leave only the upper surface. Essentially, I want to use a slightly smaller cylinder generated in Blender as a "cookie cutter" to remove everything but the top surface.

I have tried all the Boolean operations but `intersect`, `union`, and `difference` are not producing what I need. It will only keep what is *outside* the "cookie cutter" cylinder and I need what remains on the *inside*..... but without the "cookie cutter" itself getting attached to the finished object.

Here are some screen grabs, the last is what I want the end result to look like, I did this manually in MeshLab which is tedious and inelegant:

[image: "difference" Boolean with the template cylinder active]
[image: "difference" Boolean with the original object active]
[image: What I want it to look like (done manually; tedious and inelegant]